# How to display Category, Sub-Category and get product based on selected Sub-Category in MVC Dot net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new to MVC dot net. For an e-commerce app I need to populate category and subcategory. By clicking on subcategory all product should display based on selected subcategory. But I don't how to solve this one..

Here is my Model

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Subcategory Table in database:

```
SubcategoryId    SubCategoryName     CategoryId
  1                 NIKE                 1
  2                 ADIDAS               1
  3                 FENDI                2
  4                 GUCCI                2
```

Controller:

```
CategoryManager manager=new CategoryManager();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = manager.GetCategories();
        ViewBag.SubCategories = manager.GetSubCategories();
        return View();
    }
```

View for Controller:

```
@using EcommerceApp.Models;
@{
List<Category> allCategories = null;
  allCategories=  ViewBag.Categories;
//...Code for Subcategory....//
}
 @if (allCategories!= null)
       {
           foreach (var catagories in allCategories)
            {

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#@catagories.CategoryId

                               ">
                                <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                                @catagories.CategoryName
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="@catagories.CategoryId" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>   
                                @*<li><a href="#">....Code For Subcategory...</a></li>*@
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
       }
```

Gateway For SUbCategory:

```
 public List<SubCategory> GetSubCategories()
    {
        List<SubCategory> subCategoryList = new List<SubCategory>();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        string query = "SELECT * FROM SubCategory";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            SubCategory subCategory = new SubCategory();
            subCategory.CategoryId = (int)reader["CategoryId"];
            subCategory.SubCategoryName = reader["SubCategoryName"].ToString();
            subCategory.SubCategoryId = (int) reader["SubCategoryId"];
            subCategoryList.Add(subCategory);
        }
        return subCategoryList;

    }
```

This code populates Categories but I don't know how to populate Corresponding Subcategories and get product based on subcategory ID. What do I need to write or change in Controller, Model and View?

Comment: When you click on the subcategory, navigate to another action method (ex:Products) and pass the sub category id. In that action method, query your data base table (where subcategoryId=yourCategoryIdVariable) and pass that to the view.

Comment: I Can't able to populate subcategory based on CategoryID @Shyju